# Trying to understand terminology regarding perfectly convex sets in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely perfectly convex sets in Banach spaces. In the text, the other gives the following definition(s), comments, and theorem:

> > **Definition**: Let $X$ be a Banach space. A set $K\subseteq X$ is called *perfectly convex* if and only if for every bounded sequence $x_i\in K$ and for every sequence of reals $a_i\geq 0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=1$ we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_ix_i\in K$.
>
> We also define the *center* of $K$ to be the set
> $$
> \overset{c}{K}:=\{x\in K:\forall y\exists a>0\text{ with }\lambda y+(1-\lambda)x\in K,\text{ for all }0\leq\lambda\leq a\}.
> $$
> Notice that for any $x\in X$, if we put $K_x=K-x$ we have that
> $$
> \overline{(K_x)}=\overline{K_x}-x,
> \quad\overset{\circ}{K_x}=\overset{\circ}{K}-x,
> \quad\overset{c}{K_x}=\overset{c}{K}-x.\tag{1}
> $$
> Also it is clear that $K-x$ is perfectly convex if and only if $K$ is perfectly convex.
>
> > **Theorem**: If $K$ is perfectly convex in a Banach space $X$, then
> > $$
> > \overset{\circ}{K}=\overset{c}{K}=\overset{c}{\overline{K}}=\overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}.\tag{2}
> > $$
>
> *Proof (I'm only showing the beginning of the proof, because I don't understand it from the start)*. We will show that
> $$
> \overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}\subseteq\overset{\circ}{K}\subseteq\overset{c}{K}\subseteq\overset{c}{\overline{K}}\subseteq\overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}.\tag{3}
> $$
> Of course the middle two relations are trivial. We will show the first and last one. For the first one, because of $(1)$, it is enough to prove that $0\in\overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}$ implies $0\in\overset{\circ}{K}$.

What I don't understand about the above is essentially everything. To begin, what does $K_x=K-x$ mean? Is this suppose to be $K_x=K\setminus\{x\}$? Even so, I don't see how ${1}$ holds. Also, I don't see how it's only enough to show $(3)$ holds to get $(2)$. Lastly, why is it because of $(1)$ it is enough to prove that $0\in\overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}$ implies $0\in\overset{\circ}{K}$ to get the first inequality.

Comment: $K-x=\{y-x: y \in K\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K-x$ is not $K\setminus\{x\}$ but rather $$\{a-x: a\in K\},$$ where the "$-$" in the latter expression is **vector difference** (perhaps more rigorously, $K-x=\{a+(-1)x:a\in K\}$). Intuitively, this is just a **shift** of the original set $K$. It should be clear that shifting a set ought not to change whether or not it is convex. (By contrast, removing a point from a set absolutely **will** make a difference in general, as far as convexity is concerned.)

As to why $(2)$ implies $(3)$, this is a standard trick: use the fact that $X\subseteq Y\subseteq X\implies X=Y$. So e.g. to show $A=B=C$ it's enough to show $\color{red}{C\subseteq}A\subseteq B\subseteq C$, the point being that the "leftmost $C$" in the latter expression helps us trap everything and get the equality (not merely subsethood) we want. In your case, $C$ is $\overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}$.

Finally, note that there's a typo in $(1)$: the first clause should be $\overline{K_x}=\overline{K}-x$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Any chance you know why "for the first one (relation in $(3)$), because of $(1)$, it is enough to prove that $0\in\overset{\circ}{\overline{K}}$ implies $0\in\overset{\circ}{K}$"?

Comment: @D.Math If $x$ provided a counterexample for $K$, then $0$ would provide a counterexample for $K-x$. So if we prove that $0$ can never provide a counterexample, we're done.